# Selenium cannot scroll a div element

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, screenshotexception

I have a div element and want to retrieve it's children. In order to do that i need to get them all in view, so I decided I need to scroll for them. The thing is, I get my element but when I call:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,250)",element);
```

where element is a WebElement object I get this stacktrace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 125 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'seleniumRC', ip: '192.168.115.95', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Session ID: c74e4f7f-3563-44eb-98a2-4aa6a0347761
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://****:64232/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
Command duration or timeout: 1.61 seconds
Build info: version: '2.37.1', revision: 'a7c61cbd68657e133ae96672cf995890bad2ee42', time: '2013-10-21 09:08:07'
System info: host: 'ROTIMN0L022408', ip: '135.247.143.198', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Session ID: 4b75711b-4e98-47d5-acfc-c26e417b0cb1
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, webdriver.remote.sessionid=4b75711b-4e98-47d5-acfc-c26e417b0cb1, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://*:64232/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
    at com.motive.hda.selenium.SeleniumSimulatorsTest.test02_checkHDASimulatorEfficiency(SeleniumSimulatorsTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '2.37.1', revision: 'a7c61cbd68657e133ae96672cf995890bad2ee42', time: '2013-10-21 09:08:07'
System info: host: 'ROTIMN0L022408', ip: '135.247.143.198', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:125)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or enter code here timeout: 125 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'seleniumRC', ip: '192.168.115.95', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Session ID: c74e4f7f-3563-44eb-98a2-4aa6a0347761
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://*t:64232/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
Build info: version: '2.37.1', revision: 'a7c61cbd68657e133ae96672cf995890bad2ee42', time: '2013-10-21 09:08:07'
System info: host: 'ROTIMN0L022408', ip: '135.247.143.198', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.rebuildServerError(ErrorHandler.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:107)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to scroll the page for selecting the div children if they are already loaded in the page.

Incase the div and elements are not loaded then to scroll try below code.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight," + "document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
```

Comment: If they are added the WebDriver will not retrieve them to you, since the WebDriver simulates an user, meaning it will return only those visible(so if you need to scroll some aren't visible). Also, I still do not understand why that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code:

```
//Get div element having scroll bar you want to do
WebElement scrollArea = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//")); 

// Initialize Javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// Scroll inside web element vertically (e.g. 1000 pixel)
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",scrollArea, 1000);    
Thread.sleep(1000);`
```